# Pytorch Conv2d Autoencoder Output Shape

Tags: pytorch, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I built the bellow convolution autoencoder and trying to tune it to get encoder output shape (x_encoder) of [NxHxW] = 1024 without increasing loss. Currently my output shape is [4, 64, 64] Any ideas?

```
# define the NN architecture
class ConvAutoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvAutoencoder, self).__init__()
        ## encoder layers ##
        # conv layer (depth from in --> 16), 3x3 kernels
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 3, padding=1)  
        # conv layer (depth from 16 --> 4), 3x3 kernels
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 4, 3, padding=1)
        # pooling layer to reduce x-y dims by two; kernel and stride of 2
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        
        ## decoder layers ##
        ## a kernel of 2 and a stride of 2 will increase the spatial dims by 2
        self.t_conv1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(4, 16, 2, stride=2)
        self.t_conv2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 1, 2, stride=2)

    def forward(self, x):
        ## encode ##
        # add hidden layers with relu activation function
        # and maxpooling after
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        # add second hidden layer
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.pool(x)  # compressed representation
        x_encoder = x
        ## decode ##
        # add transpose conv layers, with relu activation function
        x = F.relu(self.t_conv1(x))
        # output layer (with sigmoid for scaling from 0 to 1)
        x = F.sigmoid(self.t_conv2(x))
                
        return x, x_encoder
```

Comment: It is highly impossible to get a shape of 1024*1024 with just two convolution layers.

Comment: @planet_pluto sorry not 1024x1024, for example [1,32,32]  or [16,8,8] which can viewed as 1024.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the number of your parameters, adding an `nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((N, H, W))` or `nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d((N, H, W))`layer, in place of after the pooling layer (`self.pool`) can force the output of the decoder to have shape `[NxHxW]`.

Comment: Yes, but the decoder output will change accordingly, different than the original image shape and won't be able to train the model.

Answer (score 0):

This should work assuming the shape of the x_encoder is `(torch.Size([1, 4, 64, 64])`. You can add a Conv. layer with stride set to 2 or a Conv. layer followed by a pooling layer. Check the code below:

```py
# conv layer (depth from in --> 16), 3x3 kernels
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 3, padding=1)  
# conv layer (depth from 16 --> 4), 3x3 kernels
self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 4, 3, padding=1)
# pooling layer to reduce x-y dims by two; kernel and stride of 2
self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)

# The changes
self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(4, 1, 1, 2)

# or 
self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(4, 1, 1)
self.maxpool2d = nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2))
```

Comment: I tried it out, the loss increased dramatically!

Comment: Is your data normalized and what's the loss function you're trying to use?

Comment: No and my loss is nn.BCELoss()